# react native why is my flatlist not displaying?

Tags: react-native, expo, flatlist

€: SOLVED

Why is my flatlist not displaying anything ?

Filter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';

const showFilter = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.key}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <FlatList 
          data={item.size}
          listKey={(item, index) => `_key${index.toString()}`}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key}
          style={{height: 100, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <Text>{item.size}</Text>
            )
          }}
          numColumns={3}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          initialNumToRender={2}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
          windowSize={5}
          />
        )
      }}
    />
  )
};

export default pure(showFilter);`
```

Output of console.log(item) from the second flatlist:

```
Object {
  "color": "white",
  "size": "XS",
}
Object {
  "color": "white",
  "size": "S",
}
```

Filter.js

```
          <View style={{flex: 1, height: 250}}>
            {
              currentData() !== null ? 
              <ShowFilter data={product.color} />
              : product.onlyColors.map((el, i) => {
                return product.color.map((e, i_) => {
                  if(e.color === el) {
                    return (
                      <View style={styles.filterContainer} key={`amount-and-color-${i_}`}>
                        <View key={`color-${i}`} style={[styles.colorPalett, { backgroundColor: el }]}/>
                        <Text style={styles.amountText}>{ e.amount }</Text>
                      </View>
                    )
                  }
                })
              })
            }
          </View>
...
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

The input to FlatList `data` prop must be an array. In the nested FlatList, you are passing in a string, so `renderItem` has nothing to iterate over.

That being said, you haven't shown a sample of what `product.color` is, so there may be more issues at play here. I suspect that you don't actually want to render a FlatList inside of a FlatList, unless `product.color` is an array of arrays.

Comment: you said, product.color is an array of arrays

Comment: @Datastores11 Then you probably just want to change `data={item.size}` to `data={item}`.

Comment: I solved, it was a css failure. I have to add all flex 1 then it shows.. but thanks for help